# Using the NUC5PPYH SD card slot on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, intel-nuc

I am aware Intel doesn't have the drivers for the NUC5PPYH SD card reader for Windows 7. However I was wondering if there were any third party drivers or drivers from the manufacturer of the reader that I might be able to use.

Intel claims it is because Windows 7 doesn't support USB 3, however they specifically have USB 3 drivers for Windows 7, and I went through the whole process of installing them.

Answer (score 0):

The SD card reader is an ACPI device that Intel only provides Windows 8+ drivers for. There are several Intel I2C, GPIO, SPI, and SD devices that Intel never provided Windows 7 support for. It's not a USB device; it's connected to an internal bus in the SoC (processor).